# Required Total Sum for Column after filteration using JQuery Datatable

Tags: datatables

I have gone through the link 
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Actually it works perfect for me but also i need the total sum for Column after filteration below. Need help for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you can achieve it using this https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

Comment: @juntapao yaa but also i want to use filteration so how it is possible to use both thing at the same time.

Comment: you can use this one https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()

Comment: @juntapao can you please me by sending an example in jsfiddle

Comment: @juntapao thanks alot bro it worked for me...